# Download files from SFTP server location to local machine in Node js using npm ssh2-sftp-client

Tags: ssh2-sftp

I'm trying to download xml files present in SFTP server location into my local machine location. I've used npm package ssh2-sftp-client & using sftp.get function. Server file locations are kept in text file for ex:

```
/opt/path/xml1,
/opt/path/xml2
```

These paths are read using `fs.readfile` function & stored in array which means

```
arr[1] = /opt/path/xml1
arr[2] = /opt/path/xml2
```

Then using `sftp.get` & `stream.pipe` to download file in local path. Problem is xml1 is only getting downloaded & after that the code keep on running & timing out. Any idea why it's not running multiple times?

Coding in Javascript.

```
 // Reading xml file location from text file
 // array has two remotefile location
 for(var i = 0; len = arr.length; i < len; i++) 
 {
     (function (i) 
     {
         var remotefilename = arr[i];
         var localfilename = '/path';
         sftp.get(remotefilename).then(stream) => 
         {
             stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localfilename));
             // it download xml1 only after that keeps running & timing out
             // I suspect not coming out of this loop. Have tried stream.end/close,  fs.close but didn't working
        })
     })(i);
 }
```